# an issue due to miscalculation with the monthly revenue

Tags: database, data-warehouse

We have a data warehouse which contain dimensional table and sales fact table. One day, there is an issue due to miscalculation with the monthly revenue. We found the root cause is due to missing one customer in source file. How we can we improve the system to handle this issue and make the total monthly revenue still correct? Please give your assumption for the existing system and the solution to handle missing customer data.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a resource to do your homework for you. If you have a specific, technical, question then please ask it, showing what you have already tried and the issues you are facing

Answer (score 0):

The missing revenue should be associated with the "Unknown" customer so it is surfaced in the model and revealed for the source to fix it.  The data warehouse should NEVER FIX BAD DATA, just reveal it.